# How to add multiple images to single tiff in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-modules, tiff

```
var ConvertTiff = require('tiff-to-png'),
converter = new ConvertTiff();
var filePath = __dirname + '\\tifffile\\mytifffile.tiff';
var filePAth1=__dirname + '\\images\\abc1.tiff';
var filePAth2=__dirname + '\\images\\abc1.tiff';

var tiffs =[filePAth1,filePAth2];
converter.progress = function(converted, total){
    console.log("File "+total);
};
converter.convertArray(tiffs, filePath);
```

Above code not creating single tiff with multiple pages. Please help me any suggestion.

Comment: Maybe try something like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiff-multipage

Comment: I have tried this one also but it required so many dependency installation, any other solution for this ?